# Ros1 bridge for Window10

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

anyone knows if it is possible to build and run Ros1 bridge under WIN10?

https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge provides only a guide how it works under linux

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286692/ros1-bridge-for-window10/) by [fceex](https://answers.ros.org/users/34335/fceex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
You're specifically asking to build it with VS/VC++/msbuild here, correct? Not Win10-WSL.

**Comment by [fceex](https://answers.ros.org/users/34335/fceex/) on 2018-03-27**:
yes that is right. Not WSL but native Win10 ROS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since we don't have a guide how to build ROS 1 on Windows we didn't spend time on instructions for the `ros1_bridge` since it require you to have ROS 1 available. If you do have ROS 1 built on Windows the instructions to build the bridge are pretty much the same. You should be able to follow the non-Windows instructions closely.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0